# jQuery Validation not working well

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, bootbox

I am validating form using the jQuery Validate plugin, but everytime I submit form, the page is redirected to the action page. I am not only validating form but also trying to submit form using `ajax` after knowing the form is error free. I am also using bootbox alert to show errors in alerts.

Here are JavaScript files I am including

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Here is the custom.js file I used for custom JS coding

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $(".loadr").show();
        $(".send-btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(".send-btn").css("opacity", "0.5");
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $(".loadr").hide();
        $(".send-btn").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(".send-btn").css("opacity", "1")
    });
contactus();
});
function contactus()
{
    var action = $("#CommentForm").attr("action");
    $("#CommentForm").validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        errorClass: "error_message",
        rules: {
            ContactName: "required",
            ContactPhone: "required",
            ContactComment: "required",
            ContactEmail: {
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            ContactName: {
                required: "Please enter your Name."
            },
            ContactPhone: {
                required: "Please enter your Phone.",
            },
            ContactComment: {
                required: "Please enter your Message.",
            },
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            //error.hide().insertBefore(element.prev()).show("slide", '', 'fast');
        },
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
            var summary = "";
            console.log(validator.errorList);
            jQuery.each(validator.errorList, function() {
                summary += this.message + '<br />' + "\n";
            });
            alert(summary);
        },
        onfocusout: function(element) {
            $("div.error_message").hide();
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('.loadr').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.mysite.ae/contact.php",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#CommentForm")[0].reset();
                    $("#Contactmsgdiv").empty().html('<br /><div class="alert alert-success" style="border: 1px solid;"><strong> Thank you! </strong>  We have received your request and will respond shortly!.</div>');
                    $('.loadr').hide();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the html form code

```
<form class="progression-contact wpcf7" id="CommentForm" method="post" action="contact.php" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div>
                                    <p><input id="ContactName" name="ContactName" class="textInput" placeholder="Name" /></p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><input id="ContactEmail" name="ContactEmail" class="textInput email" placeholder="E-mail" /></p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><input id="ContactPhone" name="ContactPhone" class="textInput digits" value="" placeholder="Phone" /></p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><textarea id="ContactComment" name="ContactComment" class="textInput" rows="10" cols="4" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea></p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><button type="submit" class="progression-contact-submit wpcf7-submit"><span>Send Us Your Message</span></button><img src="http://www.mysite.ae/images/bx_loader.gif" style="margin-left:15px;display:none; " class="loadr"></p>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Unless the `.validate()` method is not getting called on DOM ready, the code related the jQuery Validate plugin is working perfectly well:  http://jsfiddle.net/kr7sebcw/

Comment: As long as the plugin is initialized (`.validate()` method) and you have the `submitHandler` installed (you do), it is virtually impossible for the form to bypass and submit to the default `action`.   It does not even matter what's inside the `submitHandler` function... just including it within `.validate()` is enough to block the default `action` on a valid form.

Comment: If you see validate plugin is called in contactus function and contactus() function is itself called on DOM ready

Comment: I already saw that, but it changes nothing and your code is still working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/kr7sebcw/1/ ~ In other words, the code you've shown us is working and something else is likely breaking the JavaScript entirely.  Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I was also watching console, it is error free :(

Comment: If I can get your code working in that jsFiddle, perhaps you can take the same jsFiddle and edit it to break the code, thus demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @Sparky thanks for your help and I finaly resolved that issue :)
I was actually using bootbox and forgot that bootstrap's css and js files are also necessary to use bootbox and there was also another JS file which was creating issue, I included it after above mentioned JS and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below or delete your question.  Feel free to do whichever you think will be most helpful to others.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly resolved that issue :) I was actually using bootbox and forgot that bootstrap's css and js files are also necessary to use bootbox and there was also another JS file which was creating issue, I included it after above mentioned JS and it worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to submit the form using the action just change the submit button to a regular button. This will fire off the ajax event without submitting the form. See below.

```
<form class="progression-contact wpcf7" id="CommentForm" method="post" action="contact.php" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div>
                                <p><input id="ContactName" name="ContactName" class="textInput" placeholder="Name" /></p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><input id="ContactEmail" name="ContactEmail" class="textInput email" placeholder="E-mail" /></p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><input id="ContactPhone" name="ContactPhone" class="textInput digits" value="" placeholder="Phone" /></p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><textarea id="ContactComment" name="ContactComment" class="textInput" rows="10" cols="4" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea></p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><button type="button" class="progression-contact-submit wpcf7-submit"><span>Send Us Your Message</span></button><img src="http://www.mysite.ae/images/bx_loader.gif" style="margin-left:15px;display:none; " class="loadr"></p>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Comment: **This will not fire off his `ajax()`**.  The `ajax()` is part of the OP's  `submitHandler` function, which will only get fired when a `type="submit"` is clicked on a valid form.  In other words, the OP's `ajax()` should already be working, and the type of button is not breaking his JavaScript.

Comment: He'll just have to tie the logic in submitHandler to the button outside of the validate function.

Comment: Or try calling $('#CommentForm').submit(false);